# Use awk to count number of /bin/false entries in a file in field7 with a single command for total count

Tags: linux, awk

I am having trouble using awk to count the number of /bin/false entries in a file in field7 with a single command.

I can use grep no problem. I can use awk to count a few different ways. I have this:

```sh
awk '/false/{print NR}' /etc/password
```

but it's not printing "just the count of lines" that have `bin/false` in the 7th field. I need to incorporate $7 somehow but can't find any help with it. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
daemon:x:2:2:Daemon:/sbin:/bin/bash
ftp:x:40:49:FTP account:/srv/ftp:/bin/bash
daemonuser:x:50:59:nouser/bin/false:/home/nouser:/bin/bash
gdm:x:106:111:Gnome Display Mgr daemon:/var/lib/gdm:/bin/false
haldaemon:x:101:102:User for haldaemon:/var/run/hald:/bin/false
lp:x:4:7:Printing daemon:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/bash
mail:x:8:12:Mailer daemon:/var/spool/clientmqueue:/bin/false
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
sshd:x:71:65:SSH daemon:/var/lib/sshd:/bin/false
olivert:x:1001:1003:Tom Oliver:/home/olivert:/bin/csh
smiths:x:1049:1000:Sue Williams:/export/home/smiths:/bin/csh
northj:x:1003:1003:Jim jones-North:/home/northj:/bin/csh
denniss:x:1005:1003:Sue Dennis:/home/denniss:/bin/bash
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smithd:x:1055:1001:Dan Smith Jr:/export/home/smithd:/bin/csh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F: '$7 ~ /\/bin\/false/ { print }' /etc/passwd | wc -l
```

- `-F:` tells `awk` to use `:` as the field separator
- `$7 ~ /\/bin\/false/` compares only field 7.
- pipe the output into `wc -l` to count the lines.

Alternatively, without using `wc -l`:

```sh
awk -F: '$7 ~ /\/bin\/false/ { count++ } END {print count}' /etc/passwd
```

You might find this of interest too:

```sh
$ awk -F: '{ print $7 }' /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c
     38 /bin/bash
     79 /bin/false
     11 /bin/sh
      1 /bin/sync
      1 /bin/true
      1 /usr/local/bin/ftponly
     17 /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using putty. When entered it gives an error awk: warning escape sequence '\/' treated as plain '/' I tried using the alternative

Comment: what version of awk are you using?

Comment: gnu awk version 4.0.1

Comment: Im sorry beginner mistake it works.

Comment: I would have used `$7 == "/bin/false"`

Comment: yeah. i started out with `$7 ~ /false/` and then changed it to `/\/bin\/false/`